# How can I reset share passwords for WD Sharespace using root in SSH?

Tags: ssh, password, network-attached-storage

I have a Western Digital ShareSpace Disk Array NAS (Same one in this manual : https://docs.rs-online.com/49a1/0900766b80ce7e97.pdf )

The system has an existing number of shares, with a lot of files and data. Each share was created through the web interface of the NAS and each has its own username and password.

I am able to login to the NAS SSH interface (as root) and when I run the command

```
less /etc/passwd
```

I can see the share usernames listed.
I have the ability to change the password for any of them using

```
passwd [any_share_username_here]
```

and the change is done. But when I try to mount the share from Windows, I am prompted to enter the username and password. The new password I entered in SSH does not seem to work.

I guess the NAS has a separate credentials for accessing the share, and a different password for SSH.

Is there a way (from SSH) to alter or remove the password or create a new share the is can be exposed to Windows?

Can I reset the admin password used to login to the web interface?

EDIT: just to clarify: I already have access to the share volumes from SSH, and I can browse all of the data. I just need to be able to map to the volumes from Windows, but I can't because I don't reset the password without the web interface.

Comment: remind to verify, that some of old stations support smb v1 only which is disabled thesedays. moreover dont try to use special characaters and use as example 8 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For samba users the password is changed with smbpasswd.